# linux sh; redirect stdout/stderr to [root,adm] owned directory from within script of non-root privileged user

Tags: redirect, sh

I'm trying to redirect stdout and stdin from within a script, designed to be run by either root or a privileged user, to a directory (/var/log/backups/) which is owned by root, group syslog.  It works fine when run as root, but not when run as a user belonging to group syslog.

```
$ grep syslog /etc/group
adm:x:4:syslog,ubuntu,me
syslog:x:108:me
$ ls -dl /var/log/backup
drwxrwxr-x 2 root syslog 4096 Jun  8 14:17 /var/log/backup
```

part of my script:

```
LOG_DIR="/var/log/backup/"
sudo_cmd=    
user=`whoami`
if [ ${user} != "root" ]; then
  sudo_cmd="sudo"
fi  
echo "sudo_cmd: " ${sudo_cmd}
...
logfile=${LOG_DIR}${filnam}.log
${sudo_cmd} touch ${logfile}
${sudo_cmd} chgrp syslog ${logfile}
${sudo_cmd} chmod 664 ${logfile}
${sudo_cmd} exec >> ${logfile} 2>&1
```

Even when run outside of the script, the redirection fails when run as a not-root user with group write access:

```
$ ls -l $logfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root syslog 0 Jun  8 15:08 /var/log/backup/foo.log
$ ${sudo_cmd} exec >> ${logfile} 2>&1
sh: 13: cannot create /var/log/backup/foo.log: Permission denied
```

clues?

Comment: run the command `groups` with the userid that fails to verify that the userid belongs to syslog

Comment: See "grep syslog /etc/group" above; user "me" is in the syslog group.  "groups" shows the same thing.